# meaning of \n and \d when used in ed?

Tags: unix, ed

I want to edit a file. I want to search for a string and delete the line containing the string and 19 lines before it.

I found a similar question on another site (the topic is closed now), and the answer given was to use the following ed commands (The first command was to delete X lines before the PATTERN
and the 2nd command deletes X lines after the PATTERN);

```
ed -s file <<< $'g/PATTERN/-X,.d\n,p'
ed -s file <<< $'g/PATTERN/.,+Xd\d,p'
```

I have tried the first command and it works, but I do not understand the meaning of the \n and the \d in the first and 2nd command respectively. I think the \n might be "next line", but why is this necessary if you are going to print (,P) all lines anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can test the command passed to "ed" with a simple echo:

```
 $ echo $'g/PATTERN/-X,.d\n,p'
 g/PATTERN/-X,.d
 ,p
```

So in fact the `\n` only indicates the end of the first command, and is replaced within your shell. This has no meaning for `ed` but for your shell.

As you said `g/PATTERN/-X,.d` removes all the line from -X line to current position of the lines matched by PATTERN

`,p` show all the lines from the file

In the second command, the `\d` is just an error. And you should read it as `\n`.